# c# StreamWriter uses 50% cpu

Tags: c#, cpu, streamwriter

I've tried everything that I can think of and I'm about ready to pull my hair out.  I have an application that communicates with a modem using a TCPClient, NetworkStream, StreamWriter and StreamReader.  The modem will only accept one connection every hour or so, so I must leave my connection open.  I just switched to a new modem which apparently stops communicating after several hours, but leaves its network connection open.  I have set the NetworkStream.ReadTimeout and NetworkStream.WriteTimeout properties to 1000ms, but instead of the StreamWriter timing out when the modem stops communicating it simply begins using 50% of my computer's cpu.  There is no infinite loop, it is stopping on a single StreamWriter.WriteLine() in my code.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Sounds like a driver problem to me

Comment: could you please provide code, may be bug, may be environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere, perhaps even in code you only use but did not write, there is a loop that looks something like this:

```
while (condition)
{
    condition = checkCondition(); //possibly looking for new data from the socket
}
```

You have a dual core computer, and this loop is eating up all the cpu time from one core. The easiest way to fix this is to add a sleep call to the loop:

```
while (condition)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    condition = checkCondition();
}
```

But again, this code may be hidden in a function call you're using, where you can't change it. If that's the case, you may need to look at the classes you're using and find an alternate method of waiting for data that does not rely on the offending function.

You can find out which function is causing the problem by running your app in the bugger, wait for it to reach the problem state, and pause execution. Step through the program a bit and it should become fairly obvious where your problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It turns out that the problem is internal to System.IO.StreamWriter.  I created my own StreamWriter.Write method and it solved the problem.